# How to color the face of a cube object drawn with Opentk

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, opengl-compat, face

I am trying to color the faces of a cube object I have drawn here with `opentk`. I have registered a method that lets me listen on keyboard key presses to color a face with a specified color. Currently the cube object is drawn with a white color that it is impossible to know the shape of the cube against a black window background. I have checked the official documentation of `opengl` and they suggest that in order to color a face of a cube, you need to invoke the function `gl.color3(float red, float green, float  blue)` on the `instance`. The code that to draw the object is here, is it possible to color the face of the object when a keyboard key is pressed. Here is my code

```
//extend the GameWindow class
class MyWindow : GameWindow
{
   public MyWindow(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings) : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
    {
        WindowState = OpenTK.Windowing.Common.WindowState.Normal;
      //register a listener for keyboard events
        KeyDown += MyWindow_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MyWindow_KeyDown(KeyboardKeyEventArgs obj)
    {
        switch (obj.Key)
        {
            case Keys.W:
                //rotate cube upwards
                Console.WriteLine("Rotating object upward");
                //opengl function to rotate the cube downwards
                GL.Rotate(15, OpenTK.Mathematics.Vector3d.UnitZ);
                break;
                case Keys.S:
                Console.WriteLine("Rotating object downward");
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                Console.WriteLine("Rotating object to the left");
                break;
            case Keys.D:
                
                GL.Rotate(15, OpenTK.Mathematics.Vector3d.UnitY);
                GL.Color3(0,0,0);
                break;
             case Keys.P:
                //color a face on keypress with a different color
                 
                break;
        }
    }
    //method that draws the cube inside the GameWindow object
      protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
    {


        

        Context.SwapBuffers();

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        this.DrawBox(0.5f);
        base.OnUpdateFrame(args);

    }
      //the cube drawing logic method
     private void DrawBox(float size)
    {
        float[,] n = new float[,]{
            {-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
            {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f}
        };
        int[,] faces = new int[,]{
            {0, 1, 2, 3},
            {3, 2, 6, 7},
            {7, 6, 5, 4},
            {4, 5, 1, 0},
            {5, 6, 2, 1},
            {7, 4, 0, 3}
        };
        float[,] v = new float[8, 3];
        int i;

        v[0, 0] = v[1, 0] = v[2, 0] = v[3, 0] = -size / 2;
        v[4, 0] = v[5, 0] = v[6, 0] = v[7, 0] = size / 2;
        v[0, 1] = v[1, 1] = v[4, 1] = v[5, 1] = -size / 2;
        v[2, 1] = v[3, 1] = v[6, 1] = v[7, 1] = size / 2;
        v[0, 2] = v[3, 2] = v[4, 2] = v[7, 2] = -size / 2;
        v[1, 2] = v[2, 2] = v[5, 2] = v[6, 2] = size / 2;

        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
        for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
        {
      // s
            GL.Normal3(ref n[i, 0]);
            //GL.Color3(1, 1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 0], 0]);
            GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 1], 0]);
            GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 2], 0]);
            GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 3], 0]);
        }
        GL.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the color before drawing the quad. Define a color for each of the 6 sides. (This colors are just examples):

```cs
float[,] colors = new float[,]{
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}
};
```

If you want to change the color when you press a key, you need to change the values in array of `colors`.

Set the color with `GL.Color3` before drawing the quad:

```cs
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
{
    GL.Color3(ref colors[i, 0]);
    GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 0], 0]);
    GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 1], 0]);
    GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 2], 0]);
    GL.Vertex3(ref v[faces[i, 3], 0]);
}
GL.End();
```

Comment: It worked but I need to color with the press of a button, color face 1 with yellow when i click Y or something

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU Yes  I know.  I clearly mentioned: *"If you want to change the color when you press a key, you need to change the values in array of colors."*. You have to do change the color when a key is pressed `colors[0,1] = 1.0f`. Of curse `colors` must be an attribute instead of a local variable.